# analytical solution for ode contain Ln

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:
$${\frac {\partial }{\partial y}} \left( \alpha\, \left( y \left( x
 \right) \ln  \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) + \left( 1-y \left( x
 \right)  \right) \ln  \left( 1-y \left( x \right)  \right) +\omega
 \left( y \left( x \right)  \left( 1-y \left( x \right)  \right) 
 \right)  \right)  \right) ={\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}y
 \left( x \right)$$

we have to boundary condition y(-infinity) = 0, y(+infinity) = 1.

α and ω are constant.

Is there any analytical solution to solve that differential equation.

Comment: Is that really a partial derivative with respect to y?

Comment: @paul , with simplify equation we have: $$\alpha\cdot \ln  \left( {\frac {y \left( x \right) }{1-y \left( x
 \right) }} \right) +\omega\cdot( 1-y \left( x \right) )={\frac {{\rm d}
^{2}}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}y \left( x \right)
$$